# How to use Chaining with Nested, Revealing Module Patterns in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining, method-chaining, revealing-module-pattern

I'm struggling to get my head around a couple of JS patterns joined together: the **revealing module pattern**, and the **chaining pattern**.

What I would ideally like to be able to do is invoke multiple methods from a single initialising function like this:

```
components
    .loader()
    .menu()
    .toolbar();
```

And this works perfectly as long as any methods I define publicly `return this;`.

Things start to go wrong however when I need to nest revealing module patterns in order to expose deeper methods that are invoked outside of the initialisation like this:

```
components
    .menu
        .close();
```

The problem  doing this is that `menu` no longer returns `components`, but instead returns it's child methods which means it breaks the chain at this point. Here is a "complete" example to illustrate what I am try to achieve:

```js
var components = function () {

    var loader = function () {
        console.log("components.loader initialisation");

        return this;
    }

    var menu = function () {
        console.log("components.menu initialisation");

        var open = function () {
            console.log("components.menu.open");

            return this;
        }
        var close = function () {
            console.log("components.menu.close");

            return this;
        }

        return {
            open: open,
            close: close
        }
    }();

    var toolbar = function () {
        console.log("components.toolbar initialisation");

        return this;
    }

    return {
        loader: loader,
        menu: menu(),
        toolbar: toolbar
    }
}();

$(function () {

    components
        .loader()
        .menu()
        .toolbar();

    components
        .menu
            .open();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### So I guess my question is, how can I use; nested, revealing modules and chaining together (if at all possible)?

Comment: first of all, what do you expect menu to be? a method of component or a module. Both (although possible) is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: So just to clarify, you expect `components.menu` to return `components` (along with the `open` and `close` methods) and `components.menu.close()` to also return `components` or just `components.menu.close()` to return `components`? Perhaps updating the post to include the output expected for a few a queries would be helpful.

Comment: My apologies, I'll add some further examples for clarification.

Comment: @Thomas I need menu to setup the code inside menu, so it has events for opening and closing etc. But I need to allow Open and Close to be called by other functions so a toolbar item might trigger a menu open or close for instance. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var components = (function () {

var loader = function () {
    console.log("components.loader initialisation");

    return this;
};

var menu = function () {

    var menu = function () {
        console.log("components.menu initialisation");
  
        return this;
    };
 

    menu.open = function () {
        console.log("components.menu.open");

        return this;
    };

    menu.close = function () {
        console.log("components.menu.close");

        return this;
    };

    return menu;
};

var toolbar = function () {
    console.log("components.toolbar initialisation");
 
    return this;
};

return {
    loader: loader,
    menu: menu(),
    toolbar: toolbar
};
})();

$(function () {
components
 .loader()
 .menu()
 .toolbar();

components
 .menu
  .open();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! Would you mind just explaining why this works over the RMP? Why does menu work as both a function `.menu()` and an object `.menu`?

Comment: In Javascript function is also an object. And every object can contain its own properties. So inner variable menu is a function (can be used as menu()) and this inner menu has properties close and open (can be used as menu.close()).